# Solve Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm a newbie for mathematics and now I'm learning PDE and stuck on that. Could anyone help me out to understand this elimination from PDE. The equation is similar to solve  $$(D^2 -6DD'+9D'^2)u = y\cos x$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

$$
(D^2-6DD'+9D'^2)u=y\cos x\equiv (\partial_x^2-6\partial_x\partial_y + 9\partial_y^2)u = y\cos x
$$

we have

$$
(\partial_x-3\partial_y)^2u = y\cos x
$$

This can be solved as follows:

$$
\cases{
(\partial_x-3\partial_y)v = y\cos x\\
(\partial_x-3\partial_y)u = v
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

So given PDE is $$(D^2 -6DD'+9D'^2)u = y\cos x\implies (D-3D')^2u=y\cos x$$
Solution of the homogeneous PDE $~(D^2 -6DD'+9D'^2)u =0~$ is $$x~\phi_1(y+3x)~+~\phi_2(y+3x)$$where $~\phi_1~$ and $~\phi_2~$ are arbitrary functions.

For the non-homogeneous part, particular integral, P.I. is
$$\dfrac{1}{(D-3D')^2}~y~\cos x=\dfrac{1}{D-3D'}\cdot\dfrac{1}{D-3D'}~y~\cos x$$
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=\dfrac{1}{D-3D'}\cdot\int y~\cos\left(\frac 13(c-y)\right)~dy$$where $~c=y+3x\implies x=(c-y)/3~$
$$\text{P.I.}=\dfrac{1}{D-3D'}\left[-3y~\sin\left(\frac 13(c-y)\right)+9 \cos\left(\frac 13(c-y)\right)~\right]~~~~~~$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{D-3D'}\left[-3y~\sin\left(x\right)+9 \cos\left(x\right)~\right],~~\text{as}~~~~~~c=y+3x$$
$$=\int \left[-3y~\sin\left(\frac 13(c'-y)\right)+9 \cos\left(\frac 13(c'-y)\right)\right]~dy~~~~$$where $~c'=y+3x\implies x=(c'-y)/3~$
$$\text{P.I.}=-9y\cos\left(\frac 13(c'-y)\right)-54\sin\left(\frac 13(c'-y)\right)~~~~~~~~~~$$
$$=-9y\cos\left(x\right)-54\sin\left(x\right)~~~,~~\text{as}~~~~c'=y+3x~~~$$

Hence the general solution of the given non-homogeneous PDE is
$$u(x,y)=x~\phi_1(y+3x)~+~\phi_2(y+3x)-9y\cos\left(x\right)-54\sin\left(x\right)$$
where $~\phi_1~$ and $~\phi_2~$ are arbitrary functions.

---

For details about the formulas used here see the following link:
$(1)~~$ [Solutions of Non-homogeneous Linear Partial Differential Equations with Constant
Coefficients](http://182.18.165.51/Fac_File/STUDY182@911912.pdf)
$(2)~~$ "[Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.schandpublishing.com/books/higher-education/mathematics/ordinary-partial-differential-equations/9789352836109/)" by  M.D. Raisinghania